# Hex file to string array?

Tags: python, hex

I have files in an obsolete format that have key strings and numbers I would like to extract. If I view the file in a hex editor, I can see the information as strings. How can I read in this hex file and print out the desired strings using python?

Here is a small sample:

```
ÎFª∆3.0B International Inc.ANONYMOUS, ANONYMOUS 1269959PL 1Thu Sep  2 09:39:29 2004MMWed Aug 25 12:26:17 2004[GTV]øº—¯øÃ—¯@ˇ˝ôôôö?øÒ\ƒzO§kø∏˜QÎÖ@5ëÎ8QÎÖ?@o◊Á@p(@[ø! @n}†@p∫!@r⁄˚Ä?@Y2.16.840.1.113662.2.12.0.3012.1093437427.1484=P¡AP beamˇˇˇˇˇˇ¸-B-21EX10718X@YAAB@Yhh¥Z@4@D¿¿@FÄ?@4@D¿$¿$@FÄ?
µÏì‡ê??????????????????????????@4@D¿4¿4@N?@ÃÃÃÃÃÕ@ÃÃÃÃÃÕ@@øÒ\ƒzO§kø∏˜QÎÖ@5ëÎ8QÎÖ?øÒ\ƒzO§k@!€È  ≠k¥@5ëÎ8QÎÖ?
µÏì‡ê
µÏì‡ê
µÏì‡ê?ˇˇˇˇ
µÏì‡ê
µÏì‡ê
µÏì‡ê@Yˇˇ¸ˇ2ÑÄ?ÁWuwWux?›]’›]’‡?˙˙Çæ†Ø§?ŸDA¯˜&ëó???ˇˇ¸ˇˇ˛I?“I$íI$í???í€?‚I$íI$í???$m?Îm∂€m∂€???  ∂ˇ@VÅüÇ§u¿øÒ\ƒzO§kø∏˜QÎÖ@5ëÎ8QÎÖ?øÒ\ƒzO§k@!€È ≠k¥@5ëÎ8QÎÖ?CerroAAAÖÓ@I
µÏì‡ê@N
µÏì‡ê@ 
µÏì‡ê
µÏì‡ê
µÏì‡ê1¿ô`@√Ê†?¿
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of the input?

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to the unix tool [`strings`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strings) ?

Comment: I posted a portion of a file above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for something similar to the unix tool [`string`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strings), you can [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) the file and then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to extract the sequences of consecutive *bytes* in the printable range (32 to 127 assuming strings in your "legacy" file are encoded using ASCII).

Here is a possible starting point:

```
fname = 'wine_gecko-2.24-x86.msi'
threshold = 5

with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(mm, lambda b: 32 <= ord(b) <= 127):
         if k:
             gs = b"".join(g)
             if len(gs) > threshold:
                 print(gs)
```